# Emissive Material in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I am trying to make that a sphere emits light by using a material from the own unity, but no light is being created or emitted. What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well I answered you as what you need is the object to be visible with more or less intensity in the scene even if it is dark. Is that what you need or you need that the gameObject casts also some light over the near by objects as well?

Comment: if you want the object to light up your scene you have to make it static. if you want it to be non-static or you want the light to influence non-static objects, you will need to fake the emission with an actual light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved only checking all objects in the scene as Static!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the emission in the material, without any special shader

[image]

You can then switch off all lights in the scene and you will be able to still see this GameObject

You can test it adding a script that make the ambient light to be dark grey

```
void Start () {
        Color myColor = new Color32( 0x0B, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0xFF );
        RenderSettings.ambientLight = myColor;
    }
```

The result would be something like this, a cube which emit yellow light and a cube which is almost in darkness

[image]

Now if you want (which I am still not sure) to iluminate other elements in the scene. You should select the object as static in the right top corner.

[image]

And the result would be:

[image]

If this solution still does´t work for you. You can try with shaders:

1. Create a new Shader, name it Glow and replace its default code by this:

Script

```
Shader "Glow" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Glow ("Intensity", Range(0, 3)) = 1
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
        LOD 100
        Cull Off
        ZWrite On
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                half4 _MainTex_ST;
                fixed4 _Color;
                half _Glow;

                struct vertIn {
                    float4 pos : POSITION;
                    half2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                    half2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert (vertIn v) {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.pos);
                    o.tex = v.tex * _MainTex_ST.xy + _MainTex_ST.zw;
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag (v2f f) : SV_Target {
                    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, f.tex);
                    col *= _Color;
                    col *= _Glow;
                    return col;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create a Material
3. Change its color to what you want and the Shader type select Glow
   (the one you created in the fist step). Also choose the intensity you prefer.

[image]

The result would be:

[image]

With this version, you can not iluminate the nearby objects.

Finally, to make a better glomming effect you can add some effects to the camera.

1. Go to Assets -> Import Package -> Effects
2. Select the Main Camera and Add Component: Image Effects -> Bloom and
   Glow -> Bloom Optimized

You will have the following component in your camera:

[image]

And the result of adding this effect to the camera would be:

[image]

Comment: I've tried this, but the problem appears to be much more complex. I simply increase the value, but nothing happens.

Comment: But what do you need exactly? That the object is visible even in a dark scene, or you want the object cast some light over the neighbour objects?

Comment: @SérgioWilker Try the new things I added in the edit. Maybe some of them will help you

Comment: @SérgioWilker it would be a lot easier to help you if you could define what you expect and where the actual problem lies. "the problem appears to be much more complex" and "i increase the value, but nothing happens" could mean anything.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre The problem was solved only checking all objects in the scene as Static, thanks everyone.